# Cannot authenticate with ADRMS MDE using the MIP SDK to decrypt an RMS message

Tags: mip-sdk

I am attempting to decrypt an rpmsg using the MIP SDK and the AD RMS integration (via the Mobile Device Extension). I have this working in my environment without issue, but one of my customers receives the following logged error (from mip_sdk.miplog). While on the surface, this appears to be a simple permissions error, this was previously working and to my knowledge nothing in the permissions settings in IIS or the underlying /my server root have changed:

The request is to: [https://rms2019.customer.int/my/v1/enduserlicenses]

```
<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">
<head>
<title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id=""header""><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id=""content"">
 <div class=""content-container""><fieldset>
  <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What are the possible explanations for this error? The authentication with ADFS appears to be working, and this error is returned from the MDE.